# Is possible to install WSO2 Identity server features on WSO2 App Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have tried several options to install IS on App Server and using different repositories but it always complains about some packages. What is the easy way to get the correct dependencies and repositories?

This is an example of the errors:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. 
Software being installed: 
STS Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.sts.feature.group 4.2.1)

Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.1) 
Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - 
Carbon Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.1) WSO2 Carbon - 
Carbon Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.2.0)

Comment: what is the wso2IS and wso2AS version that you use?

Answer (score 2):

What version of IS and what version of App Server are you running?  I have never tried to implement the scenario you are but I could see you getting that type of error if the version of App Server you are running is on Carbon 4.4 and the version of IS is still on Carbon 4.2.  The current 5.0 release of IS runs on Carbon 4.2 but I think the 5.1 release of IS runs on Carbon 4.4 and should be available before long.

Joe

Comment: I tried several versions, for the App server 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.3.0. In all of them I tried to install the IS feature version 5.